# How to mount data volume outside container?

Tags: docker

I have to make a container in A directory and mount in B directory that /home/B. Now how to mount Container A in B so that I can read files from B. I just want to make 1 container that is in A directory and need to read files of B directory so for this I am mounting it. Here is what I have wrote in dockerfile

```
From python:2.7-slim 
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app 
RUN ls
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying but unable to understand how to mount in different directory. I know how to mount in same container.

Comment: Answer given by Goolishka will enable you to mount container's `/common_dir` directory to your local file system's `/home/B` directory. Isn't it what was asked in the question?

Comment: You have to read Docker documentation, it is very good explained and there are a lot of online examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker run --name=container1 -v /home/B:/common_dir <image_name>
docker run --name=container2 -v /home/B:/common_dir <image2_name>
```

after it you have 2 running containers with the common folder /home/B on your host
both 2 containers can read/write to /home/B

Comment: Thank you, Also to read files I have write this in docker file From python:2.7-slim 
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app 
RUN ls  But it is not working

Comment: Also which is this common_dir?

Comment: when you run the contaner, the -v key has signature <local_folder>:<container_folder>. as example docker run -v /home/username/B:/app will mount your local B folder into the containers /app folder

Comment: Great Big help...I have change WorkDir to B directory but still it is not listing the files. It does not give any output